# SharePoint PnP PowerShellOnline - Add-PnPFolder Error "Cannot contact site at the specified URL"

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I am using SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline version 3.29.2101.0 and have successfully connected and  authenticated to my Teams SP site.  However, I get the following error when I try to create SP folders: "Add-PnPFolder : Cannot contact site at the specified URL ...  There is no Web named ...".  Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Are you seeing the same thing with the replacement 'PnP.PowerShell' module? https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PnP.PowerShell/

Comment: I think, in your script, **Shared Documents** is the name of the document library where you are creating folders at, but it's not a site or sub-site name. Remove the library name from  variable $URL and try again.

Comment: @TrevorSeward - I ran Get-Module and it shows I already have PnP.PowerShell 1.2.0.

Comment: @MatiurRahman - I removed the folder part of the URL and the error was "File Not Found".  

This is the underlying SharePoint site for MS Teams.  Also, the code I have executing has been working for some time now until I upgraded SP PnP PS.

Answer (score 1):

The following script worked for me, that is,**TestFolder** was created in "Shared Documents" library root. The site was created when an MS Team was created (MS Teams default site).

```
Import-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Verbose

#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MSTeamsSite"
 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -SPOManagementShell

Add-PnPFolder -Name "TestFolder" -Folder "/Shared%20Documents"
```

Comment: I ran your script and got this error: "Add-PnPFolder : Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl".

Comment: I'm using PnpPowerShellOnline 3.21.2005.2, Not sure if it has anything to do. However, the error msg that your are getting indicates that you need to add the relative path like *"/sites/your team site name/Shared%20Documents"*

Comment: Thanks for your help @MatiurRahman.  I can't get it to work in my tenant with a relative path or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the credential on **site level**. Put the URL of the site instead of the library for the parameter `$URL`.

Here is a sample script:

```
$SiteUrl = <SiteURL>
$Username = <AdminAccount>
$Password = <Password>
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credential $cred

#Skip this line if you already have Folder General in the Shared Documents library
Add-PnPFolder -Name General -Folder Shared%20Documents

#Create SubFolders in Shared Documents > General
Add-PnPFolder -Name "Teams Training" -Folder Shared%20Documents/General
```